# Quasi-linear time fully homomorphic encryption using p-adic ring homomorphism

Tags: cryptography, p-adic-number-theory

I recently encountered a [breakthrough in FHE crypto](http://www.ijtpc.org/volume1/JTPC1386.pdf), which claims to have a literally quasi-linear time FHE without any "lambda" factor in the keys and **no** noise in the cipher-text.

This fully homomorphic encryption works like for addition like $E(m_1)·E(m_2) = E(m_1+m_2)$ and for multiplication like $E(m_1)^{m_2} = E(m_1·m_2)$ ; they say they achieved it using p-adic exponential.

My Question is: What is exactly p-adic exponential?

Comment: What you describe is not fully homomorphic. Notice that $m_2$ in the second equation is not encrypted.

Comment: Hasn't he defined it in P1.3? Were you looking for more than that?

Comment: A warning about the paper: it doesn't sound like the author knows much about crypto.  There's the misrepresentation of FHE that Mike pointed out; in addition, he claims his system is Informationally Secure (which is impossible for any public key system); he claims that a message cannot be uniquely decrypted; if this were true, this would imply that someone with the private key cannot decrypt it.  His claim of $O(n \log n)$ time is also bogus.  I would approach this system only with extreme caution.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question (and ignoring the fluff), the $p$-adic exponential is a partial function on the $p$-adic numbers defined by the power series

$$ \exp(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $$

This power series converges if and only if $x$ is a $p$-adic integer divisible by $p$. It satisfies many of the properties you'd expect. For example, $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x) \exp(y)$, and it has an inverse, the $p$-adic logarithm.

If you're not familiar with the $p$-adic numbers, we can approximate them with modular arithmetic. If $x$ is an integer such that $x \equiv 0 \pmod p$, then the above power series also makes sense in the arithmetic of integers modulo $p^n$. For an example with the $3$-adic logarithm:

$$\begin{align} \exp(3) &\equiv 1 + 3 + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{27}{6} + \cdots& \pmod{27} 
\\ &\equiv 1 + 3 + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{9}{2} + 0& \pmod{27} 
\\ &\equiv 1 + 3 + 9 \cdot 14 + 9 \cdot 14 & \pmod{27}
\\ &\equiv 13& \pmod{27}
\end{align}$$

Note the remaining terms (indicated by $\cdots$) are all divisible by $27$, which is why I replaced withm with $0$ in the above calculation. And that $2$ and $14$ are inverses modulo $27$: i.e. $2 \cdot 14 \equiv 1 \pmod{27}$.